# Looking for jQuery slideshow where a user can hide/show a block of text (link, caption)

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm looking to implement a fairly basic jQuery slideshow. One that automatically loops through a set number of images.  The snag I'm running into is i'd like to have a little icon in the corner of the picture, that when clicked, brings up a transparent black bar across the bottom with some text and perhaps a link.  Has anybody come across anything like this?

This gallery is close, but lacks user control for showing/hiding the caption (and might be somewhat restrictive of what text can be used): http://www.queness.com/resources/html/slideshow/jquery-slideshow.html

Anyway, if anybody has any tips or links that would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the classic theme in Galleria:

http://galleria.aino.se

Comment: I've used that with another project - but it doesn't have the main feature I'm looking for, a toggle switch for users to hide/show a caption or link. Unless I missed it.

Comment: See the 'i' square in the top left corner? try clicking it.